# Laravel add seperate key-value pair to collection JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a Laravel controller that returns a collection of items (in this case Answers):

```
return AnswerResource::collection($correctAns);
```

This returns a JSON object as expected of course. How would I go about appending an item to that object so it's more like this?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "answer_text": "True"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "answer_text": "False"
    }
  ],
  "testKey": "arsnteio12345"
}
```

(where the testKey thing is what's added)

Comment: I'm not sure what `AnswerResource` is, but you _should_ be able to store as variable and modify prior to return, like `$res = AnswerResource::collection($correctAns); // Code to modify $res; return $res;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
return Response::json(['data '=> $correctAns, 'testKey' => 'arsnteio12345'],200);
```

Comment: I updated it to the response()->json() syntax it uses now, but that works! I didn't think I could just return $correctAns before turning it into a collection of resources. Thanks for your help.